# Using the Imperative of 'Aller' in Informal Situations

Tags: grammaire, verbes, impératif

I have come across this situation several times and find it rather curious.

There exists both an informal and a formal imperative of 'aller' (as with any imperative), these being 'va' and 'allez' respectively. I would therefore expect a mother telling her child to get off the floor and stand up to say "va, debout". Yet I heard her say "allez, debout".

Why is she using 'allez' instead of 'va' with her little toddler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"allez" is used here as an interjection. From [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/allez%C2%A0_/2372) :

> **allez !**
>
> interjection
>
> Exprime l'encouragement, l'affection, la menace, etc. : *Allez ! on se retrouvera.*

It would be translated as *come on! ("Come on, get up")*

Answer (score 2):

Should you want to use *aller*, a possible sentence could have been:

> « Vas-y, debout ! »

or even, as *allez* as already stated is an interjection here:

> « Allez, vas-y, debout ! »

*Va* alone is too literary to be used in that context but can be found in this famous verse:

> «  Va, cours, vole et nous venge ! »
>   – Corneille, le Cid